# Send email with attachment

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I need to send email along with attachments which reside in a different platform to external email IDs. below is the code snippet which I have done so far. Please suggest how to proceed further.

**Rest Class**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/sendPDFEmail/*')
Global class GETPDFContent{
 @HttpPost
global static void sendEmail(String EmailIdCSV, String Subject, String body) 
{

List<String> EmailIds = EmailIdCSV.split(',');

    PageReference ref = Page.PDF_DEMO;
    ref.getParameters().put('id', '00590000000ZiGV');
    //Id is User ID
    Blob b = ref.getContentAsPDF();

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa1.setFileName('attachment_WORK.pdf');
    efa1.setBody(b);

    String addresses;
    email.setSubject( Subject +String.valueOf(DateTime.now()));
    email.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );
    email.setPlainTextBody(Body);
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa1});
    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

}
```

}

**Controller**:

```
 public with sharing class PDFController {

 public User u{get;set;}
 public Account Acc{get;set;}
 public Id accountId{get;set;}

 public PDFController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
 accountId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
 //Acc =[Select id, Name,Phone FROM Account];
 u = [Select id,AccountId,Name, Account.Name,Account.phone from User where 
 id=:accountId limit 1];
 acc = [Select Id, Name,Phone From Account Where Id =: u.AccountId];

 }

 // Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
 public String getCalloutResponseContents(String url) {

// Instantiate a new http object
Http h = new Http();

 // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');

// Send the request, and return a response
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
return res.getBody();
}

}
```

**VF Page**:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="User" 
extensions="PDFController"  sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" 
applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" >
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
        }

           @page {
            size: letter;
            margin: 20mm;      
            }
    </style>
  </head>


  <br/>
<br/>
 <apex:outputText style="font-size: 13px;background-color: yellow;" value="
 {0,date,MMMM dd, yyyy}">
  <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" />


 </apex:outputText>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Figure out a way to read the attachment data from the "different platform". Typically you will need to first authenticate and then make [HTTP or HTTPS requests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http.htm) to get the data. Apex includes the building blocks you need for this but the details depend on exactly what the "different platform" offers.
2. Use the Apex `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`and `Messaging.EmailFileAttachment` classes to send the email addresses. There is an example of that sort of code in the [Creating an Email Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm) documentation.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner The data being public makes it much easier. I've added a link to the Apex HTTP classes you can use to request the data.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code which I have tried. Not sure how to proceed further to send the mails. Please suggest.

Comment: @SalesforceLearner The links in my answer provide examples: you'll hardly ever find exactly the code you need. Instead you need to experiment and fix compile errors and runtime errors (use the debug log) until you figure it out.