# Send email with attachment through REST

Tags: rest-api, email, apex-email-service

I need to send email along with attachments which reside in a different platform (public URL) to external email IDs. Below is the code snippet which I have done so far. Please suggest how to proceed further.

**REST API**:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/sendPDFEmail/*')
Global class GETPDFContent{
@HttpPost
global static void sendEmail(String EmailIdCSV, String Subject, String body) 
{
List<String> EmailIds = EmailIdCSV.split(',');

PageReference ref = Page.PDF_DEMO;
ref.getParameters().put('id', '00590000000ZiGV');
//Id is User ID
Blob b = ref.getContentAsPDF();

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa1 = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa1.setFileName('attachment_WORK.pdf');
efa1.setBody(b);

String addresses;
email.setSubject( Subject +String.valueOf(DateTime.now()));
email.setToAddresses( EmailIds  );
email.setPlainTextBody(Body);
email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa1});
Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});

}
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public with sharing class PDFController {

public User u{get;set;}
public Account Acc{get;set;}
public Id userId{get;set;}

public BankMandariPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
userId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
//Acc =[Select Account.Name,Account.Phone,(Select Id,Card_Number__c FROM 
Cases) FROM Account];
u = [Select id,AccountId, Name from User where id=:userId limit 1];
acc = [Select Id, Name,Phone  From Account Where Id =: u.AccountId];
}

// Pass in the endpoint to be used using the string url
public String getCalloutResponseContents(String url) {

// Instantiate a new http object
Http h = new Http();

// Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the 
endpoint
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setMethod('GET');

// Send the request, and return a response
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
return res.getBody();
}
}
```

**VF Page**:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="User" 
extensions="PDFController"  sidebar="false" renderAs="pdf" 
 applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" >
 <head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
    }
       @page {
        size: letter;
        margin: 20mm;      
        }
  </style>
  </head>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <apex:outputText style="font-size: 13px;background-color: yellow;" value="
  {0,date,MMMM dd, yyyy}">
  <apex:param value="{!TODAY()}" />
  </apex:outputText>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Don't know how to connect the external platform's URL in REST and when trying to run the VF page, it gives error:  "System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
Class.PDFController.<init>: line 10, column 1". Its talking about the User object query. I need to send the mail on a button click.

Comment: Your field `accountId` should be named `userId` if it contains a`User` Id. You need to pass in a valid `User` `Id`.

Comment: Earlier copy of question [Send email with attachment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190383/send-email-with-attachment).

Comment: @KeithC Since the previous question is on hold, so had to open a new question. I have updated my code and changed the AccountId to UserId. Still no luck. Same error.

Comment: If you're initiating a data send to an external system, you don't need to build a REST API in Salesforce.  You only need that if you want the external system to initiate data operations with Salesforce.

Focus on your controller making the HTTP callout to the external system.